# User Profile not updating and no errors is given

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am having an issue while i want to update my user profile in my django project. It is not updating, not saving to the database and not showing any error in the terminal.

Here is the form:

```
from django import forms
from .models import CustomUser, Profile

class UserUpdateViewForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False)
    phone_number = forms.CharField(max_length=20, required=False)
    address = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['image', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'address', 'phone_number']
```

Here is the View:

```
from django.forms.models import BaseModelForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, UpdateView
from .models import CustomUser,Profile
from .forms import UserUpdateViewForm

class UserProfileView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'account/account.html'  # Change this to the template name you want to use

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['user_profile'] = self.request.user  # Assumes a one-to-one relationship between CustomUser and Profile
        return context
    
class UserProfileUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Profile
    form_class = UserUpdateViewForm
    template_name = 'account/update_profile.html'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        # Get the user's profile to be updated
        return self.request.user.profile
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save()
        success_url = reverse_lazy('profile_page')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(success_url)
```

Here is the template too

```
{% extends 'base/base.html' %}
{% load static %}


{% block content %}
<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <!-- User Profile Image -->
            <div class="text-center">
                <img src="{{ user_profile.profile.image.url }}" alt="User Image" class="img-fluid rounded-circle"
                    style="width: 200px;">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <!-- User Profile Details -->
            <h2>Update {{ user.username }}'s Profile</h2>
            <hr>
            <form action="{% url 'update_profile_page' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6 mt-3">
                        <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" value="{{user.first_name}}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6 mt-3">
                        <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name" value="{{user.last_name}}">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group mt-3">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" value="{{user.email}}">
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3 mt-3">
                    <label for="Image" class="form-label">Image</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="file" id="Image" value="{{ user_profile.profile.image.url }}">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group mt-3">
                    <label for="phone_number">Phone</label>
                    <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone_number" value="{{user.phone_number}}">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group mt-3">
                    <label for="address">Address</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" value="{{user.address}}">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-5 mb-5">Save Changes</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

I dont know where the error is coming from. it's giving me headache. I want the profile to be updated and the details to be saved to the database.

Comment: Could you share `models.py` please? Usually, with a `CustomUser` there is no `Profile`

Answer (score 0):

You can debug it by trying below things:

First check your form is valid and getting expected data. for this add print statement in `form_valid` function `print(form.cleaned_data)`.

If your not getting anything in form_valid function that means your form could have some error to debug that you can add funtion or add error tag in form

```
# Add funtion in UserProfileUpdateView
def form_invalid(self, form):
    print("Form is invalid. Errors:", form.errors)
    return super().form_invalid(form)

# Add error tag in html for each field
 <span>{{ form.first_name.errors }}</span>
```

If you are design form by yourself then add the name attribute for all field

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" name="first_name" value="{{user.first_name}}">
```

Hope you got the point where you are missing by doing above things.